# Set default location for Terminal window opened with Ctrl+Alt+T

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-terminal

I want to change the command line of gnome-terminal to include geometry of both size and location. I already know how to set size using the configuration editor, but not location.

There must be some file I can edit to add `--geometry 80x55-500+0` to get the terminal where I want it. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> what actually happens? How do I use it to change the window location?

Comment: I've edited your question because it felt like it's an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Feel free to rollback the changes (rollback button [here](http://superuser.com/posts/625181/revisions)) if you feel like your real intentions are lost.

Comment: Agreed - I'm still curious about "what happens", but getting to happen is the important thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click your username in the top right of the screen and select `System Settings`.
2. Under  `Hardware` click `Keyboard`.
3. Switch to the `Shortcuts` tab.
4. Click `custom shortcuts`.

[image]

Comment: 5.  Hit the + and type in the name (as shown) and command (I used gnome-terminal --geometry 80x55-500+0)

Comment: 6. Hit apply and then click on the new "Launch Terminal" where it says "disabled" and hold Ctrl-Alt-T.  Say yes to reassign from standard launch.

Comment: That works, and now I'd like to know why it works :-)  Thanks!

Comment: Man! you are a savior. I tried to edit preferences of the terminal window but failed miserably. the terminal opens up in an infinite loop. Same occurs when I try to execute the gnome-terminal command by running a shell script from bashrc file . Strange it was so easy but yes , I am curious to know why did it work in this case. Thanks.